# How to change the class of an element with JQuery to a 'nested-class'?

Tags: jquery, css, class, grouping, nested

CSS:

```
#logo-container {
  position: fixed;
  right:5px;
  .home-page {
    /* homepage style */
  }
  .content-page {   /* <-- I want to change the $element's class to this class */
    margin-top: 78px;
  }
}
```

JQuery (to change `#logo-container`'s class to `.content-page`):

```
jQuery(this).prev('#logo-container').attr('class', '#nav-container .content-page');
```

This doesn't seem to be working...Any ideas?

EDIT: The issue seems to be in how I reference `.content-page`. I've tried the following and none seem to work:

`'content-page'`
`'.content-page'`
`'logo-container content-page'`
`'#logo-container .content-page'`
`'#logo-container.content-page'`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Also `'.content-page'` and `'#nav-container.content-page'` didn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementById('logo-container').className = "content-page"`. because Id's are unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
div.a {
  color: red;
}

div.a div.b {
  /* Inherits color from div.a */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

You should check this question: [nested css rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720844/nested-css-rules?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).find('div').removeClass('logo-container').addClass('content-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass` to add a new class to a DOM element:

`$('#logo-container').addClass('content-page')`

If you want to remove an old class and add a new one, use `toggleClass`

`$('#logo-container').toggleClass('old-class content-page')`

Comment: It's not an issue of adding or toggling a class, but how do I reference a 'nested' class??

Comment: You just reference it by class name (e.g. `content-page`). But you need to adjust your CSS as the one currently provided is invalid. The correct CSS definition in your CSS file is most likely `#logo-container.content-page`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720844/nested-css-rules to learn more about the correct way of defining that CSS

Comment: Thanks!! It's too bad CSS doesn't allow nesting this way so that a child css id/class could inherit styles from it's parent. (Similar to the way classes in Java/C++ inherit attributes/functions from it's parent class.)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(this).prev('#logo-container').toggleClass('content-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# //this is a sign for an id
```

to remove an id you have to use removeAttr('id')

so maybe you need something like this

```
$('#logo-container').addClass('content-page').removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: your words: "JQuery (to change #logo-container's class to .content-page):" so what is the #logo-container's class? and also your words: "jQuery(this).prev('#logo-container').attr('class', '#nav-container .content-page');" so you are trying to do something with the id. a class will never listen to # - in your CSS is a "}" to much

Comment: if you google for "jquery change class of element" you will find tons of information. for me your question is not so clear to see exactly what your problem is

Comment: Nvm. thanks for the help, but I found out CSS can't do want I wanted it to do. Here is my question better stated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060405/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-css-class-within-another

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).prev('#logo-container').addClass('content-page')
```

BTW,whats for "#nav-container"?