# CSS Style Rule Declaration

Tags: css

I don't remember where I saw it or what language variation it claimed to be but I saw a style rule that had a declaration within another. It was something like the below.

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure it looked something like that and if I guessed correctly it would be the same as this:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul > li {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Can someone tell me what variation of CSS this is so I can learn more on it as it seems to be a lot simpler.

Comment: It looks like LESS: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Duplicate with [nested css rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720844/nested-css-rules)

Comment: Search `CSS preprocessor` on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most CSS preprocessor's now.. It's called `nested rules`.

[lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)

[SASS css](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

An example from the lesscss website:

> Less gives you the ability to use nesting instead of, or in combination with cascading. Let's say we have the following CSS:

```
#header {
  color: black;
}
#header .navigation {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header .logo {
  width: 300px;
}
```

> In Less, we can also write it this way:

```
#header {
  color: black;
  .navigation {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```